# Update database automatically based on current livescore

Tags: mysql

I have managed to create a website similar to http://www.livescore.com/ but only for a game in my country. But the problem that i still cannot solve is how to update the score automatically. For the current system, I need to watch the soccer game and need to update the score into the system manually. For example, Arsenal vs Chelsea and if Arsenal have scored 1 goal, I need to insert manually 1 for Arsenal and 0 for Chelsea. Is there a way to get the score and update the result automatically?

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to hook your system up with some kind of an API. Look online for any "Football score API".

Comment: is that possible that i want to do it only for soccer game in my country??

Comment: i mean the API for my country soccer game